# Single Broker, Multiple consumers

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

How can I entertain ***multiple consumers*** at the ***same time*** using same ***single broker*** in Kafka??

Comment: What specific errors are you getting when starting more than one consumer?

Answer (score 0):

All the consumers of unique consumer groups can consume same message at the same time. You need to check your configuration very carefully.

Depending upong the frequency and size of data, you should design cluster. Single Broker based configuration may affect overall performance with increase in number of users.

Can you comment more about your requirement for specific answer?